# In VSCode / Xdebug, where is the output of the Trace Function?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using Xdebug and VSCode and I want to do the following:

When I load a page of my website, any page, I want to see all the function calls.

There are these options, to put in *php.ini* :

```ini
xdebug.collect_return = 1 
xdebug.collect_assignments = 1
```

But the problem is that I don't know where is the "trace" that the [doc](https://xdebug.org/docs/trace) is referring to. Are there "trace" files ? Where is the output of this Function Trace in VSCode ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) `xdebug.output_dir` -- https://xdebug.org/docs/trace#output_dir 2) Also make sure that `xdebug.mode` contains the `trace` value (in addition to any other that you may need) -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, seems to work, but do you know how to reduce the output to only name of php files that are called (I don't need to get the name of the functions actually)

Comment: I'm note sure it's possible. But you can try `xdebug.trace_format` to `1` and then alter https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/contrib/tracefile-analyser.php script to output only desired info.